# Cannot see timeline-posts posted via developer-app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I want to post to facebook company-page via a developer-app. Therefore I created an app and also an access-token with the following permissions:

```
manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, public_profile
```

Posts are successfully created on the company-page via the app.
The problem I have is the following:

1. Customer is posting on the companies page.
2. Answer from the company is posted via the api (app).
3. The customer sees that there is an comment to his initial post but he cannot see the content of the reply.

I'm pretty sure my access-token is missing some permission but I could not find anything related in the facebook api documentation. Or am I wrong and there is another problem?

Comment: is the app public? check your settings.

Comment: The app is under development (app-status), maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the App is public in the App settings: App Review > "Your app is in development and unavailable to the public."

Postings of Development-Apps usually don´t show up for regular users.